# PyCharm Duplicate Main Menu

Tags: pycharm

I just installed PyCharm Community Edition and it seems like I have duplicate Main Menu for some reason.....

[image]

I did some search but doesn't seem to find a solution. How can I get rid of the second menu? Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I exit the full-screen mode and re-enter it on mac then the main menu became normal. I didn't have to restart nor reinstall PyCharm the bug somehow disappeared and the main menu looks normal again.

I did report this to JetBrains but due to me unable to recreate the problem, JeBrains closed the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to simply reinstall PyCharm, or just restart your computer.

Along with that, you should report the bug to JetBrains so that they can identify and fix the issue.